# Unable to perform filter n sorting in ag-grid for agNumberColumnFilter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

> I am displaying an ag-grid in react app which has a column with
>   decimal number. I am using this column to display the decimal number
>   in both English(ex: 100.00) and Italian number format(ex:100,00). I am
>   able to display in both formats but filter n sorting is not working
>   for Italian format.

```
 {
            headerName: fieldLabelEn.PRICE, field: "price", cellStyle: {},
            sortable: true, menuTabs: ["filterMenuTab"], maxWidth: 210,
            filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter', suppressSizeToFit: true,
                     valueGetter: params => {
                if (params.data.price!== '' ) {
                    if (numberDisplayFormat === "Italian/Norwegian/Spanish") {
                        return params.data.price;
                    } else {
                        return parseFloat(params.data.price.replace(/,/g, ''));
                    }
                }
            return null
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `valueGetter` to do formatting, the underlying data that is passed to the grid is modified.

To be exact, the grid gets a number when display format is English whereas it gets a string when format is Italian/Norwegian/Spanish. That is the reason filtering/sorting won't work properly.

To overcome this, I would recommend using `valueFormatter` which would only modify the display and not the underlying data.

> From docs -  Value formatters allow you to format values for display.
>   This is useful when data is one type (e.g. numeric) but needs to be
>   converted for human reading (e.g. putting in currency symbols and
>   number formatting).

Value Formatter [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-formatters/#value-formatter-example)

If you want to continue using `valueGetter`, you would have to come up with custom comparator and filter functions to parse the strings

Comment: I used valueFormatter  instead of valueGetter, but still same issue

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur what exactly does not work? filtering or sorting? can you create a plunkr?